# Как реализовать множественный поиск в PosgreSQL оптимальным способом?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица в базе Postgres, в которой штук 20 столбцов. И есть задача делать выборку базы по подстроке, не зная, к какому столбцу эта подстрока может относиться.
То есть, пользователь вводит в поиск любую подстроку, а мне нужно перебрать все данные в таблице, так как подстрока может относиться к чему угодно, к любому из 20 столбцов.

Если же приходит две подстроки, нужно делать выборку, где каждая запись содержит в любом столбце хотя бы одно вхождение каждой из подстрок. И так до пяти подстрок в одном запросе.

Как грамотно организовать выборку из базы в данном случае? Какие паттерны существуют для решения такой проблемы?

Comment: Стоит задуматься о разворачивании этих столбцов в отдельные записи. Т.е. использованием структуры EAV. (Возможно дублирования для целей поиска, оставляя сами колонки в таблице как есть) И возможно использование полнотекстового поиска (если поиск подстроки идет не сначала строки, а с произвольного места) по полю значения такого EAV. Или выполнение того же самого внешними средствами, вроде elastic search

Comment: *делать выборку базы по подстроке* Подстрока - произвольная или префиксная? если первая - по-любому фуллскан, и тогда на текущей структуре невозможно придумать что-то лучше, чем конкатенация полей с разделителем, гарантированно отсутствующем в подстроке поиска (скажем, `CHAR(0)`) и поиск в объединённой строке.

Comment: @Akina подстрока произвольная. Под конкатенацией вы подразумеваете создание дополнительного столбца, в который запишется сумма всех остальных столбцов, с глобальным апдейтом базы один раз, либо конкатенация столбцов на лету, при каждом запросе?

Comment: Динамически, в запросе, само собой...

Answer (score 2):

Допущения:

- все 20 столбцов текстовые
- поиск на вхождение подстроки в любом месте строк
- искомая подстрока хотя бы 3 символов длиной
- вам всё равно, в каком из полей нашли искомое

Генерируете условия `where`

```
(f1 like '%подстрока1%'
  or f2 like '%подстрока1%' ...)
and
(f1 like '%подстрока2%'
  or f2 like '%подстрока2%' ...)
```

Чтобы не было скучно перебирать всё seqscan'ом понадобится штатный модуль [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

И индекс по полям:

```
create index concurrently on tablename using gin(f1 gin_trgm_ops, f2 gin_trgm_ops, f3 gin_trgm_ops, f4 gin_trgm_ops);
```

Для `gin` индекса порядок полей в индексе значения не имеет.

---

При дополнительном допущении что допустимо по поисковому запросу "с пробелом" вывести результат, где одно слово попало в одно поле, а второе - в другое - то можно заметно упростить запрос.

```
create index on tablename using gin((f1 || ' ' || f2 || ' ' || f3 || ' ' || f4) gin_trgm_ops);

where (f1 || ' ' || f2 || ' ' || f3 || ' ' || f4) like '%подстрока1%'
 and (f1 || ' ' || f2 || ' ' || f3 || ' ' || f4) like '%подстрока2%'
 ...
```

Длинную портянку склеивания полей можно заменить на `immutable` функцию:

```
create function test_idx_support(tablename) returns text immutable language sql as $$ select (($1).f1 || ' ' || ($1).f2 || ' ' || ($1).f3 || ' ' || ($1).f4); $$;

create index on tablename using gin(test_idx_support(tablename) gin_trgm_ops);
```

И затем искать по этой функции:

```
where test_idx_support(tablename) like '%подстрока1%'
  and test_idx_support(tablename) like '%подстрока2%'
  ...
```